# Accessing additional properties in binding in Azure Function Context

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions

I'm writing Azure Functions in TypeScript. I want to enhance one of the TypeScript function classes, `Context`. Azure Functions declare triggers, input and outputs in a json configuration file.

Here's an example of a binding:

```
{
  "name": "shipmentDocumentOut",
  "type": "cosmosDB",
  "databaseName": "dev",
  "collectionName": "shipment",
  "createIfNotExists": false,
  "connectionStringSetting": "COSMOSDB_CONNECTION_STRING",
  "direction": "out"
}
```

Bindings are bootstrapped by the function runtime environment and are then available on a `Context` object when starting:

```js
const updatePackageTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context): Promise<void> {
    const index = context.bindingDefinitions.findIndex(def => def.name === "shipmentDocumentOut")
    context.bindingDefinitions[index]
    ...
}
```

In the above snippet I access the binding definition. However, I need to access the fields `databaseName` and `collectionName`, but these are not available in the interface:

```js
export interface Context {
    bindingDefinitions: BindingDefinition[];
}

export interface BindingDefinition {
    name: string;
    type: string;
    direction: 'in' | 'out' | 'inout' | undefined;
}
```

I tried extending the context according to a [guide](https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2019-04-03-typed-bindings-for-azure-functions/) I found, but this gives me an error when I use it:

```js
interface BindingContext extends Context {
    bindings: {
        shipmentDocumentOut: {
            collectionName: string,
            databaseName: string
        }
    };
}

// Causes:
Type '(context: BindingContext, packageEvents: PackageEvent[]) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'AzureFunction'.
  Types of parameters 'context' and 'context' are incompatible.
    Type 'Context' is not assignable to type 'BindingContext'.
      Types of property 'bindings' are incompatible.
        Property 'shipmentDocumentOut' is missing in type '{ [key: string]: any; }' but required in type '{ shipmentDocumentOut: { collectionName: string; databaseName: string; }; }'
```

How can I access the properties in a configured binding? I'm guessing the Function runtime uses these properties somewhere under the hood to connect to the database.

Comment: trying to do the same thing, except to get the `route` so I can reliably map to an open api schema.  Annoying that azure does not expose this information in the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context provides its execution directory during runtime, so I solved it as follows:

```js
export class FunctionUtil {

    private static readonly _functionFileName = "function.json";

    static async getBindingByName(functionFileDirectory: string, bindingName: string) {
        const functionJson = await FileUtil.readFileAsync(`${functionFileDirectory}/${this._functionFileName}`, "UTF-8")
        return functionJson.bindings.find((binding: { name: string }) => binding.name === bindingName)
    }
}
```

To call the util:

```js
const binding = await FunctionUtil.getBindingByName(context.executionContext.functionDirectory, "bindingName")
```