# How to update key-value in bindings of functions.json

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions

so let's say my out binding in my function.json is as follows

```
"bindings": [
    {
      [in data]...
    },
    {
      "name": "funcMsg",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "databaseName": "",
      "collectionName": "collection1",
      "connectionStringSetting": "connStr",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
```

I know I can peform `context.bindings.funcMsg = "some value"`, is it possible to do the same for the `databaseName` key in my out binding in `TypeScript`?

For example

```
context.bindings.databaseName = "some value";
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use in the below format to get access the bindings

```
module.exports = async function(context, myTrigger, myInput, myOtherInput) { ... };
```

In such cases for updating databaseName, we can update its value. Refer to [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#bindings) on understanding context bindings, as we have some details about `context.bindings.name (this is a key)` Below is the way we access them:

```
module.exports = async function(context) { 
    context.log("This is myTrigger: " + context.bindings.myTrigger);
    context.log("This is myInput: " + context.bindings.myInput);
    context.log("This is myOtherInput: " + context.bindings.myOtherInput);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would I be able to directly access the databaseName in my function.json file in my typescript code, i.e. something like `context.bindings.databaseName = "my_db"` @SaiKarri-MT

Comment: The out binding of my code is for Cosmos DB, databaseName is a special key for cosmos db instance hence I don't think I would be able to access it through `name` like you would with `context.bindings.myInput`.

Comment: hey @mello 'name' is just an example, similar way you can access the databaseName. 
If you feel any confusion you can refer to this SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658831/accessing-additional-properties-in-binding-in-azure-function-context)